# My java program executeUpdate ok but the scott.emp table in oracle have no changed?

Tags: oracle

When I execute this program below, it outputs OK to the console,but the scott.emp table did not change, is there something I miss?

I have tested the sql in sqlplus and its correct

```
package com.sp;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TransationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl", "system", "system");

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement sm = conn.createStatement();


            sm.executeUpdate("update scott.emp set sal=sal-100 where ename='SCOTT'");//I have tested this sql in sqlplus and its correct.

            sm.executeUpdate("update scott.emp set sal=sal+100 where ename='SMITH'");//I have tested this sql in sqlplus and its correct.

            conn.commit();
            System.out.println("OK");
            sm.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the scott.emp table, no change:

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE              SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
 ----- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- 
  8002 JIMMY                                                7800
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-12月-80            800                    20
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-2月 -81           1600        300         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-2月 -81           1250        500         30
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-4月 -81           2975                    20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-9月 -81           1250       1400         30
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-5月 -81           2850                    30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-6月 -81           2450                    10
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-4月 -87           3000                    20
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-11月-81           5000                    10
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-9月 -81           1500          0         30
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-5月 -87           1100                    20
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-12月-81            950                    30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-12月-81           3000                    20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-1月 -82           1300                    10
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? (Not relevant, but connecting as system probably isn't a good idea; why not connect as scott?)

Comment: @Alex Poole  yes I was connecting anather database, thanks for  your advice